# Big mark separator for thousands in flextable and vtable

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

I am trying to use the separator big mark to render big numbers in a format with comma: 1,000 instead of 1000. Can someone help me make the commas appear? My code:

```
library(vtable)
library(flextable)
a<-c(1000,2000,3000)
b<-c(4000,5000,6000)
summarystat<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

table<-flextable(st(summarystat, out="return", digits=2,fixed.digits = TRUE, vars=c("a",  "b"), summ= c("notNA(x)","mean(x)","sd(x)","min(x)","max(x)"), summ.names = c("Number of Observations","Mean", "Standard Deviation", "Min", "Max"))) %>%
  colformat_double(big.mark = ",") %>% colformat_num(big.mark = ",") %>% 
  theme_vanilla() %>% set_table_properties(width = 1, layout = "autofit")

table<-table %>% font(fontname="garamond", part="all")
table
```

My code renders nevertheless as:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma does not appear at the 3rd to the 6th columns of `table` because those columns are all of `character` type. You need to change their types to `numeric` first, and then use `flextable()` and `colformat_double()` functions. You can use `map_at` to apply `as.numeric()` function to specific columns.

I have tried the following code and it works.

```
table<- st(summarystat, out="return", digits=2,
           fixed.digits =   TRUE, vars=c("a",  "b"),
           summ=c("notNA(x)","mean(x)","sd(x)","min(x)","max(x)"),
           summ.names = c("Number of Observations","Mean",
                          "Standard Deviation", "Min", "Max"))%>% 

# Here I apply `as.numeric()` to all columns other than the first column.

        map_at(-1, as.numeric) %>% as.data.frame(check.names = FALSE) %>% 
        flextable() %>% colformat_double (big.mark = ",") %>%
        colformat_num(big.mark = ",") %>% 
        theme_vanilla() %>% 
        set_table_properties(width = 1, layout = "autofit")
table <-table %>% font(fontname="garamond", part="all")
table
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works like magic!